# Mac OS Keychain

Tags: macos, keychain

What are the best ways to add, remove, modify, read, and delete generic password items from the keychain using Cocoa / Obj C? From what I've seen about keychain, it's a mess.

Comment: Do you mean programatically?  If so, in which language, with what framework, so on &c.?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has an API for it : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html
It is very low level.

What you want is probably a wrapper like this one : https://github.com/irons/EMKeychain

All of this assuming you use Objective-C / Cocoa

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simpler interface. Check out [RHKeychain](http://rheard.com/blog/2012/05/rhkeychain/).

It provides a simple and easy to use wrapper to the Mac OS X keychain to create, edit and delete generic password items.

Available on [GitHub](http://bit.ly/NXTId7). BSD Licensed.